# Curl issue using curl example from Swagger

Tags: curl

Running this curl:

```
curl.exe -X 'POST' 'https://xx.com:7072/api/xx' -H 'accept: text/plain' -H 'X-API-KEY: xx' -H 
'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"Ids": [312003],"resolution": "xx","startUtc": "2022-11- 
01T00:00:00.000Z","endUtc": "2022-11-02T00:00:00.000Z"}'
```

I get the error:

{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00","errors":{"$":["'t' is an invalid start of a property name. Expected a '"'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."],"tsValuesParam":["The tsValuesParam field is required."]}}

What is the problem here?